# how to send logs to remote Rsyslog server with desired file name with python

Tags: python, linux, logging, rsyslog

I want to send log messages in my scripts in python with logging module in desired file name to remote rsyslog server...but with environment variable in rsyslog server couldn't be done

hear is the desired python code to be working...

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.1.105', 514))
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'))

filehdlr = logging.FileHandler('//192.168.1.105/var/log/remote/filehandler.log',mode='w')

logger.info('This is a log message.')
```

any idea?
thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by *environment variable* in the context of the `rsyslog` server? Also, have you configured the rsyslog server on the receiving end to be able to receive logs?

Comment: You are trying to write directly to a remote file, which doesn't work. Instead, you can send the logs to a specific IP and port, and the rsyslog server needs to be configured to listen on that port for incoming messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The name on the remote end is decided by the rsyslog-daemon running there.

You'll need to configure rsyslog on the remote machine to take messages from your instance with a name of "my_logger" to go to a specific file.